# Passing a new empty array as a parameter

Tags: arrays, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String())`. When I add a new Key I want to add an empty array with a defined length to it, so I can add and use the values later on.

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String())()
Dim auxData(24) As String

myDict.Add(177, auxData)
```

Is there any way to add a value to the `Dictionary` without need to use a variable to use in the value? Just declaring an empty string array directly, with a specified length.

Something like:

```
myDict.Add(177, New String(24))
```

Comment: What happens when you try that code?

Comment: @JonSkeet It tries to use the [String constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) and return an error converting the integer to a char array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `{}` after the array.

```
myDict.Add(177, New String(24){})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I don't know why I didn't try that. Thanks!